# Bitmap.decodeStream returns null on specific existing (And working) images

Tags: java, android, bitmap

**UPDATE:**

After searching a bit I don't seem to be alone about this problem:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-beginners/dDnHEacrpCE

There's two solutions ATM:

1.
(Only works in some cases) Before calling the static decodeStream() method, implement a Thread.sleep(300) (Maybe the sleep duration value have to be higher, but 300 ms works for me)

2.
Replace the following:

```
URL pictureurl = new URL("http://www.somewebsite.com/picture15.jpg");
URLConnection urlConn = pictureurl.openConnection();
urlConn.connect();
InputStream urlStream = urlConn.getInputStream();
```

with the following (As suggested by imran khan):

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet();
httpRequest.setURI(new URI("http://www.somewebsite.com/picture15.jpg"));
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufHttpEntity.getContent());
httpRequest.abort();
```

I therefore accept imran khan's answer, as it's the only answer of all the answers in this post that's working.

---

I have the following code in my Android app:

```
URL pictureurl = new URL("http://www.somewebsite.com/picture15.jpg");

URLConnection urlConn = pictureurl.openConnection(); // NOT NULL
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://www.somewebsite.com/");
urlConn.connect();
InputStream urlStream = urlConn.getInputStream(); // NOT NULL

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(urlStream);
Bitmap bm2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 100, 100, true);

imageView.setImageBitmap(bm2);
```

The method "decodeStream()" returns null, when I use a certain image from a certain website **but when I load the image in my browser it shows up just fine.
I can use other images from other websites that result in the method "decodeStream()" returning the expected Bitmap instance.**

I noticed the following text in the method explanation of the "decodeStream()" method:

"*If the input stream is null, or cannot be used to decode a bitmap, the function returns null*" - My input stream **is NOT null**!

Following picture results in the method "decodeStream()" returning null:

http://i45.tinypic.com/eah2d2.jpg

Following picture results in the method "decodeStream()" returning the expected bitmap instance:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Wiktionary_small.svg/350px-Wiktionary_small.svg.png

I am using Android 1.5.

Is this a bug in the Android/Java environment or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: thera is an open issue on the android bug truck: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try following:

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet();
httpRequest.setURI(new URI("http://www.somewebsite.com/picture15.jpg"));
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufHttpEntity.getContent());
httpRequest.abort();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to pass BufferedInputStream.

BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream( is );
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( bis );
```

so your code to decode stream will be.

InputStream urlStream = urlConn.getInputStream(); // NOT NULL

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream( urlStream );
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
Bitmap bm2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 100, 100, true);
```

Comment: Using the BufferedInputStream class still results in "bm" being null.