# Decode bitmap from stream without Apache HTTP Client

Tags: android, http-get, android-bitmap

Until recently, I decoded images from a web resource using the Apache HTTP Client using this code:

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(params[0].toURI());

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufferedEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);

return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedEntity.getContent());
```

This all worked perfectly fine.

Now with Android 6, Apache HTTP Client has been deprecated. Not to worry, I thought, just use `java.net.HttpUrlConnection` instead as recommended here:

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

The code I tried and that I found in other questions here is:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) params[0].openConnection();
// connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
// connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();

InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

inputStream.close();

return bitmap;
```

This doesn't work. `bitmap` will always be `null` for the same image resource that works with the old code.

Does anyone have any insight into this? Here are other questions I tried and why they didn't work:

- [Android: bitmapfactory.decodestream returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650660/android-bitmapfactory-decodestream-returns-null) (Answers use deprecated methods/classes)
- [Bitmap.decodeStream returns null on specific existing (And working) images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225988/bitmap-decodestream-returns-null-on-specific-existing-and-working-images) (Same as above)

Comment: Hmm have you tried using Picasso or Glide to get images from a url? Both of those are great libraries that do this task really well

Comment: @Shmuel I haven't. Using a library for a task that seems so trivial is a bit over the top. I'll give it a go if no answer crops up here.

Comment: Also, your two implementations are not comparable. Delete `setRequestProperty()` and `setDoInput()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Same result though.

Comment: Then try using the `InputStream` yourself, to see if you are getting some sort of HTTP error from the server. Or, switch to a modern HTTP client, such as OkHttp. Or, keep your existing code (more or less) and use Apache's independent packaging of their HttpClient library. Or, as Shmuel suggested, use [an image-loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46).

Comment: @CommonsWare Well, what do you know. It was a http/https issue... The second implementation works just fine. Thanks for pointing me at the http error.

Comment: Error handling with `HttpURLConnection` sucks. That's why we keep inventing replacement HTTP client APIs. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you want to create an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: No, because I don't really know what you changed. :-) I suggest that you answer it and (tomorrow) accept your own answer.

Comment: `Do you want to create an answer` ..... `No`.  Now finally that you can earn some points ... you are throwing them away... ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a simple HTTP/HTTPS issue. The image resource was requested from a `http://` address. The server is set up to issue a 307 (temporary redirect) to the matching `https://` address.

Although the default of `HttpURLConnection` is to follow redirects, the code given in the question didn't work. FYI Picasso didn't load the image either.

Requesting the image via its `https://` address solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Volley or Picasso. That's the recommended approach.